# Converting continuously updating values of C loop in scala

Tags: scala

I have one `c` code.

I want to convert it in `scala`.

Here is the `c` code.

I am not getting the part How can I use continues updated values in scala?

Is it possible to use foldLeft in this case?

```
int value=9999,i,j,length=10;
```

`A` and `B` are some `2D` Integer array and `some value` is changing for every element. Its not fixed for entire loop.

```
for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
   for(j=0;j<=5;j++){
       if(A[i][j]==value && B[i][j]==value)
           length=length+44;
       else if(A[i][j]!=value && B[i][j]==value)
           if(length< 'Some value')
           length=length+11
       else
           if(length< 'Some value')
           length=length+22
     }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried to write it with scala? Just try and explain what your problem is, and you'll get help :)

Comment: You can use `for` comprehension, you can use `fold`, or a recursion. You can use `var` or `val` for intermediate results - there are so many ways to do it. You can also almost directly translate your code to Scala.

Comment: Thanks For your valuable comments. i tried foldleft and It worked for me. Thanks a lot for response. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent code might go something like this:

```
def someValue(x: Int, y: Int): Int = ... // I'm treating this as some function that takes the array values and returns an Int
val A: Array[Array[Int]] = ...
val B: Array[Array[Int]] = ...

val Value = 9999 // Capitalised, so it can be used directly in case matches 

( for {
  i <- 0 to 5
  j <- 0 to 5
} yield ((i, j)) ).foldLeft(10){ case (length, (i,j)) => (A(i)(j), B(i)(j)) match {
    case (Value, Value) => length + 44
    case (other, Value) if other != Value =>
      if (length < someValue(A(i)(j), B(i)(j))) {
        length + 11
      } else {
        length
      }      
    case _ => length
  }
}
```

I left off the second comparison of `length` against `someValue` because it isn't clear how this code could ever be reached in the `C` code above.

Comment: Thanks for your response :)